# ALL context removal does not apply

Tags: dax

I have defined the following table :
[image]

The following measure does not work as expected :

```
VAR lt_MAX_DATE =
    FILTER(
        ALL(    dim_CALENDAR[DATE]  )   ,
        dim_CALENDAR[DATE]  =   MAX(    dim_CALENDAR[DATE]  )
    )

VAR lv_MAX_YEAR_DAY =
    CALCULATE(
        VALUES( dim_CALENDAR[YEAR_DAY]  )   ,
        ALL(    dim_CALENDAR  ) ,
        lt_MAX_DATE
    )

RETURN
    lv_MAX_YEAR_DAY
```

as I get :
[image]

In my mind, I should get `10` for both rows of the `Max Date ALL` column, but this is not the case.
My question is : why does a `dim_CALENDAR[YEAR]` context apply even though I have used the `ALL()` function?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `DAX` measure to return the max **`Year_day`** of **`maxYear`** by ignoring no matter what **`year`** is currently visible in the filter context, you can achieve it in many ways. Two of them are as below.

```
Measure1 = 
VAR mxYr =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( dim_Calendar[Year] ), ALL ( dim_Calendar[Year] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( dim_Calendar[Year_day] ),
        dim_Calendar[Year]=mxYr
    )


Measure2 = 
VAR mxYr =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( dim_Calendar[Year] ), ALL ( dim_Calendar[Year] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( dim_Calendar[Year_day] ),
        TREATAS ( { mxYr }, dim_Calendar[Year] )
    )
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 2):

This expression

```
VAR lt_MAX_DATE =
    FILTER(
        ALL(    dim_CALENDAR[DATE]  )   ,
        dim_CALENDAR[DATE]  =   MAX(    dim_CALENDAR[DATE]  )
    )
```

is the same as

```
VAR YEARinMatrixRow = SELECTEDVALUE[dim_CALENDAR[YEAR]]
VAR lt_MAX_DATE =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        FILTER(
            ALL(    dim_CALENDAR[DATE]  )   ,
            dim_CALENDAR[DATE]  =   MAX(    dim_CALENDAR[DATE]  )
        )
        ,dim_CALENDAR[YEAR] = YEARinMatrixRow 
    )
```

So, the result of the expression is the last date of the selected (in Row) year. You get a Row  filtering.

The second expression filters the table by

```
ALL(    dim_CALENDAR  ) 
,lt_MAX_DATE
```

According to DAX priorities, first works ALL(dim_CALENDAR) , then you apply filter - lt_MAX_DATE

So, you get the dim_CALENDAR table, simply filtered by the last day of the year in a matrix row where you get  a single value with the VALUES( dim_CALENDAR[YEAR_DAY]  ).

You overite ALL( dim_CALENDAR  )  by the  - lt_MAX_DATE

Normaly, you will get an error with lv_MAX_YEAR_DAY syntax. Calculate returns scalar value, while VALUES() function returns a table even with 1 cell.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mik says, you are restricting the context with

```
dim_CALENDAR[DATE]  =   MAX(    dim_CALENDAR[DATE]  )
```